# indexof returns -1

Tags: c#

When my string is `mail&mail@mail.com`, the code returns -1.

How can I solve that?

```
email = mail&mail@mail.com
int arroba = email.IndexOf("@");
```

I also tried this:

```
int arroba = email.IndexOf("@", email.IndexOf("&"));
```

Any help serves me thanks

Comment: Would you find this easier to use: https://es.stackoverflow.com/ or https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ (It could be either!)

Comment: Try [es.so] or [pt.so] instead, that might be easier for you to explain your issue.

Comment: @Jamiec - if you write `[es.so]` in your comment it will auto expand the full URL (or `[pt.so]`).

Comment: Can you provide compiling code that shows the issue?

Comment: Both times `arroba` becomes `9` for me. What is your **real** issue?

Comment: Does it help if you use email.IndexOf("@", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the char you search has different culture from the one in your email string.

Try this:

```
email = "email = mail&mail@mail.com";
int result = -1;
int and = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(email, "&");
if(and!=-1)
result = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(email, "@");
```